# Problem with accessing the methods due to Multilevel and Multiple inheritance in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 3 classes as stated below -

***AWSClient***

This class is responsible for creating the clients for the AWS resources being used in the application.

```
import boto3


class AWSClient:

    def __init__(self):

        self.region_name = "ap-south-1"
    
    def get_dynamo_client(self):

        try:
            self.dynamo_client = boto3.resource("dynamodb", region_name=self.region_name)
        except BaseException as e:
            raise Exception("Some error!")
        
        return self.dynamo_client
            
    def get_ses_client(self):
        return True
```

***DynamoTable***

```
class DynamoTable(AWSClient):
    """
    This method will use attributes of AWSClients to create dynamo table instance.
    """

    def __init__(self):

        # Now we can access the attributes of AWSClients' __init__() method.
        AWSClients.__init__(self)

    def get_admin_table(self):
        """
        This method will create the client for table Admins.
        """

        try:
            table = super(
                DynamoTable, self).get_dynamo_client().Table("Admins")
        except ClientError as e:
            raise e
```

***BaseModel***

```
class BaseModel(DynamoTable):
    """
    This class will act as a base for all developers while creating models.
    """
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        # Now we can access the attributes of DynamoTable's __init__() method.
        # Additionally, attributes of AWSClient can also be accessed as DynamoTable 
        # is inheriting AWSClient.

        DynamoTable.__init__(self)
```

The relations among the classes above is -

`AWSClient` is a super class of `DynamoTable` and the `DynamoTable` is a super class of `BaseModel`.

Now inheriting `BaseModel` other developers might create their own model classes. However, in some cases the developer's model class might want to get clients of other AWS services like `get_ses_client()` and it could be done via calling a specific method of class `AWSClient()`.

Here is what I have tried so far -

```
class InviteAdminsModel(BaseModel, AWSClient):
    
"""
This is a sample model for Admins table.
This must be in the helper module of each API.
All the API specific interation with dynamo should be written in the methods of this class.
"""

def __init__(self):
    """
    This method will have all the clients of dynamo table initialized.
    
    """
    
    BaseModel.__init__(self)
    
    self.admin_table = super(BaseModel, self).get_admin_table()
    self.ses_client = super(BaseModel, self).get_ses_client()
```

In the implementation above I am able to get the client of `admin_table` but I am not able to call the method `get_ses_client()` which belongs to `AWSClient()`. It throws me an error `super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`.

Is this the correct implementation for `InviteAdminsModel()`?

How can I call the methods of `AWSClient()`?

Should `BaseModel()` be an abstract class?

Comment: By subclass do you mean superclass, or is your syntax wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me point out few mistakes you have made.

```
class DynamoTable(AWSClients):
```

I see there is a typo , it must be `AWSClient` not `AWSClients`

> `AWSClient` is a subclass of `DynamoTable` and the `DynamoTable` is a
> subclass of `BaseModel`.

No, it is super classes not subclasses

`AWSClient` is a superclass of `DynamoTable` and the `DynamoTable` is a superclass of `BaseModel`.

And in your `InvoteAdminsModel`, you need not use multiple inheritance lie

```
class InviteAdminsModel(BaseModel, AWSClient):
```

As, `AWSClient` is already a parent of `MaseModel`. Just use

```
class InviteAdminsModel(BaseModel):
```

With these modifications, it should work fine. I hope you understood the problem ,and how it gets solved.

Comment: I have corrected the typo and now instead of inheriting `BaseModel` & `AWSClient` in `InviteAdminsModel` I am just inheriting `BaseModel`. But it still throws the same error. Hence, this question cannot closed as it is reproducible.

Comment: Still there is a typo at AWSClients.__init__(self)